# Integrate Text Editor With IPad App - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have an app for a text editor developed by OMNI Group. I need to integrate this text editor with one of my other apps. I have no idea as to how should I do it. Can someone provide me any directions as to how should I begin with it. I googled a lot but could not find much help. Thanks and regards.

Comment: what do you mean by integrate?

Comment: what do you want to integrate, code files, or generated text file from the app.?

Comment: i need to be able to edit some text(in the WebView) using that editor through my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**: Assuming that your text editor is an online editor living in a browser, simply implement a `UIWebView` and it should just work. For example, an editable `<textarea>` is rendered without problems in a `UIWebView`.

If you need other special features you have implemented with javascript and the like you need to test if they work in the `UIWebView`.

**2**: If, however, the text editor is already working in another iOS app, simply copy the classes that you are using to implement the editor into your new project and use them in an equivalent way, tweaking where necessary. If you followed the programming principle of *incapsulation* this should be a breeze.